# jQuery for and load waiting for image

Tags: jquery, plugins, load

Hi i have a problem inside my first plugin :-)

i set some vars inside a for loop
the problem is that when i try to remove the image, i end up to try to remove 3 time #img-3
like if it get execute later when variable already changed value

```
for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {

  var insertImg = arrImgs[i];
  var deleteImg = '#img-' + i;

  $('<img src="'+ insertImg +'">').hide().appendTo('#mydiv').load(function(){
      $(this).show(0, function() {
           deleteImg.remove();                          
      });
  });

}
```

Comment: `deleteImg` is a string. It does not have a `remove()` method. Please post the actual code you are using.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `$(deleteImg).remove();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `deleteImg.remove();` is a typo, and that you actually meant to post `$(deleteImg).remove()`, there are a couple of problems here.

1. You are not adding an ID to the image element you are inserting. Try using:

   ```
   $('<img src="'+ insertImg +'" id="' + i + '" />')
   ```
2. The callbacks are closing over the `deleteImg` variable, and will only use the value stored in it when they are invoked. Seeing as they are invoked in response to an event (the load event), this will be *after* the loop has completed, at which point the value of `deleteImg` is "#img-3".

   One solution to this problem is to use an IIFE to pass the value from `deleteImg` without closing over the variable. This would look like:

   ```
   .load((function(d){
       return function(){
           $(this).show(0, function() {
                d.remove();                          
           });
       }
   })(deleteImg));
   ```

Comment: thanks! yes was a typo. How can i prepare the 3 images and wait for all 3 of them are loaded to proceed?